# Dropbox.API SDK not working from Azure server

Tags: asp.net, azure, oauth-2.0, firewall, dropbox-api

I am using Dropbox's .Net SDK to upload a file to my Dropbox with a valid access token. The code works fine while executing from "localhost".

But deploying the same on Azure server, code doesn't execute and no error/response returned by Dropbox and no file uploads.

Dropbox confirmed that code's behavior should be same in all .NET environments. They are claiming that it may be because of Azure servers firewall or antivirus security may block the request to Dropbox.

Could anyone help me on this to make it work on Azure environment, or how can I trace the firewall-blocked requests in Azure server?

Below is the sample code,

```
public async Task<bool> UploadFile(string accesstoken, string folder, string filename, byte[] file)
    {
        try
        {                    
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var dropbox = new Dropbox.Api.DropboxClient(accesstoken))
                {
                    var response = await dropbox.Files.UploadAsync("/" + folder + "/" + filename, WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance, body: new MemoryStream(file));
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

I got the above from the [Dropbox blog](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/06/introducing-a-preview-of-the-new-dropbox-net-sdk-for-api-v2/)

Comment: You don't need the `using (var client = new HttpClient())` using block.

Comment: HttpClient inherits from IDisposable, therefore, Dispose() should be called at some point. The using statement, in most cases, is the best way since it implements a try,catch,finally to ensure all resources are released, even with an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The problem resides on the path's folder name and its white spaces.

The alternate approach we used was, upload file to dropbox using Core API instead of using SDK.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs

Below code works well with Core API

```
public async Task<bool> UploadFile(string accesstoken, string foldername, string filename, byte[] file)
        {
            try
            {    
                string url = "https://content.dropboxapi.com/1/files/auto/" + foldername;

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accesstoken);

                    var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                    var fileContent = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(file));
                    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                    {
                        Name = "\"file\"",
                        FileName = "\"" + filename + "\""
                    };
                    fileContent.Headers.ContentType =
                        MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filename));
                    requestContent.Add(fileContent);

                    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, requestContent);

                    return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Then another issue with SDK is, Task.wait() or Task.Result doesn't receive any response from Dropbox for long time and let the timeout/task cacelled exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

The DropBox SDK seesm to have an error if there is white space in the path you are saving to. This only happens if you are setting the path dynamically.

In the code sample, if `folder` or `filename` have spaces, the call won't work. If you are using a literal string, then spaces are ok.

Not sure what is happening inside the SDK, but this behaviour can be shown to happen in test projects.

To make it even more confusing, this works for localhost but not when we wrote a test app and deployed it to Azure!